# Как обойти родительский элемент, с позиционированием, что бы задать ширину 100% от ширины контейнера сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, есть менюшка, куда встраивается выпадающий список, который должен быть на всю ширину контейнера

[image: ![картинка]

Но ему мешает вот этот вот блок

[image: http://prntscr.com/f3893b]

у которого также абсолютное позиционирование, а сделать float-ом нельзя так как будет сдвигаться логотип, который должен быть строго по центре,

[image: http://prntscr.com/f38a0c]

также нельзя вынести его из списка с абсолютным позиционированием, так как там с массива вытягивается как пункты меню так и списки к ним. Как можно такое чудо реализовать?)

Comment: если сделать float-ом то все норм получается http://prntscr.com/f38aql , возможно лучше спросить как сделать, что бы лого оставалось строго посередине (верстка адаптивная)

Comment: Расположите в вопросе картинки не как ссылки, а как картинки..тут имеется такой функционал. И  если надо дополнить вопрос - нажмите "править", а не добавляйте комментарий.

Comment: ага, и примитивную верстку сделайте, гд будет понятен пример